# Why did Helmut Zemo target only James Buchanan Barnes and not 5 other Winter Soldiers?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

We saw in *Captain America: Civil War* that Zemo used Bucky as a means to make the Avengers crumble from within.

When Tony saw the footage he was enraged and the Avengers literally broke up.

All I want to do is point to the fact that instead of using Bucky to make the Avengers fight among themselves, why didn't he use the other 5 winter soldiers,

Also, we know those 5 were stronger than Bucky and maybe equal to Cap if not more.

Comment: @Ankit Sharma thnx for the edit, I wasn't able to add them tags due to my low rep

Comment: I'd say the title is misleading - Helmut Zemo definitely targets all the Winter Soldiers, he kills them all in their tanks. Can you clarify? Maybe "Why did Helmut Zero use James Buchanan Barns to break up the Avengers?"

Comment: @masterArSuKa How can you say they were better than Bucky and How can you say Bucky is a lesser compared to Cap? you said **we know those 5 were stronger than Bucky and maybe equal to Cap if not more.**

Comment: @Vishwa This one is easy, Bucky admits this himself in Captain America:CivilWar.Also we can see the new Winter soldiers tossing Bucky and over powering him very easily. Also, "if those five were to work together, they could bring down a nation in one night !!" says Bucky.

Comment: When did he admits that? We can see new recruits tossing bucky around at **first** because Bucky didn't get them seriously. We can see when they statred to attack everyone including doctors, Bucky was forced by one soldier to take him out safely and Bucky was shown doing that easily. Him saying *if those five were to work together, they could bring down a nation in one night* is a notion about their training. That's what winter soldier program was about.It has no indication that Bucky was/is any inferior than them.

Comment: It's more like an opinion going by what you said, but the way Bucky explained Cap about them Winter soldiers, his tone and expressions reflected so, this was why Cap was convinced to go to Siberia by any way possible, at any cost.

Comment: I think that scene was focused on how much damage can be done by any winter soldier and then what will happen if somebody get the full control of five of them. Bucky knows what they could do, he was the first success. So it doesn't mean Bucky was any inferior but what will happen if Zemo get control of *five winter soldiers*, considering the damage he did by himself so far...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Firstly, because if he had resuscitated the other "Winter Soldiers" there is no guarantee he would have been able to control them as he did Bucky.

That's assuming he could *find* them. I don't recall that he knew where they were until midway through the movie.

As Bucky said...

> He wanted to know about Siberia.
>
> Where I was kept.
>
> He wanted to know exactly where.
>
> Because I'm not the only Winter Soldier.

But more importantly, he's against **all** powered/enhanced people because of what they did to Sokovia...he just uses Bucky as a *weapon* that is available.

He specifically tells the Avengers when they discover the dead soldiers...

> Did you really think I wanted more of you?

So, it wasn't about making more enhanced people, it was about using *one* to destroy the Avengers. He didn't need the other 5 to do that.

Comment: also he can't get any leverage on Cap or Stark from other five. Bucky was the link to everything

Answer (score 30):

Zemo chose Bucky because Bucky killed Tony's parents. This drives the wedge between Tony & Steve which breaks up the Avengers. He says he couldn't defeat the Avengers even if he tried, as stronger men have tried and failed but if he can turn them against one another, then he can truly defeat the Avengers.

Controlling any other Winter Soldier would not make Tony & Steve Rogers into enemies. The other Winter Soldiers didn't kill Tony's parents.

Comment: *and aren't Steve's best friend

Comment: When did Zemo learn that Bucky killed Tony's parents? If that information was in the encrypted Hydra files, then all Zemo had to do was send that evidence to Tony. - Zemo kept asking ___"Mission report, December 16, 1991"___ suggesting that he didn't actually know what exactly happened that night. - And if the russion Colonel had given up that information, then Zemo wouldn't have had to go after Bucky at all. Bucky was simply the only other person he could get to, after the Colonel, who had the information he needed.

Comment: @Oliver_C as far as I remember, it is not explicitly stated that Zemo knows that Bucky killed Tony's parents. But if he didn't know then the monologue at the climax about destroying Avengers from within doesn't make much sense because he it looks like he just got lucky to get info. that could break up the Avengers. He's primary goal was to destroy Avengers who killed his family. He's secondary goal was to destroy Winter Soldiers. He was asking mission report to know the location of the Winter Soldiers. But he already had the info. about Tony's parents.

Comment: Zemo needed Bucky alive & captured to know the location of Winter Soldiers to execute his secondary plan of killing them. If he just emailed the info to Tony, & Tony killed Bucky, he wouldn't know their location in Siberia

Comment: @KharoBangdo - Zemo asked specifically about what happened on __"December 16, 1991"__, so it wasn't just information on a location he wanted. - And Bucky isn't an Avenger, so even if he knew Bucky did something bad, the most he could hope for was that Cap would defend Bucky against Tony. - Zemo was lucky that the Sokovia Accords split the Avengers beforehand. He was also lucky that the airport fight went the way it went (e.g. Natasha switching sides). He was lucky that Cap hadn't already told Tony about what Bucky did ...

Comment: @Oliver_C you can know when Tony's parent's died, and know when WS were active, and guess connections, but you'd still need the full details to confirm it. You also need enough proof to convince Tony.